# Head/Tail in lists Java

Tags: java, head

Is it possible for a Linked list to have  null header but not a null tail? I mean when the header is null does this mean that the list is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't make much sense from a logical point of view does it? So no.

Especially if you look at the actual implementation of the LinkedList in Java which uses **one** element as both head and tail (the last element of the list is the prev element of the dummy node, the first element of the list is the next element).

Answer (score 2):

If the head is null, it should mean that the list is empty. If not, the linked list data structure is implemented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If the header is null so is the tail. The "tail" of a list is the rest of the elements after a given element, if the header is null then by definition it doesn't have any more elements, so the tail is null. And yes, a null header means that the list is empty.